# How to override a function from outer script

Tags: javascript

I want to override a function getClusterProperties() from https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.44.1/mapbox-gl.js

But simply adding my own function getClusterProperties(cluster){...} after script loads did nothing.

```
  <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.44.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='map'></div>
  <script>
  function getClusterProperties(cluster) {...override}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be in the global namespace. How do you call this function normally?

Comment: I guess, you are using it like this: mapbox.getClusterProperties(), so you could override it like this
mapbox.getClusterProperties = funcntion() {...} after mapbox is loaded. However, I would suggest you not to do that, because you don't know how this library is implemented. Maybe it uses getClusterProperties method internally and if you override it you can mess up the whole library. Just create your own function.

Comment: @MátéSafranka actually I don't call it, it is called somewhere in mapbox

Comment: As far as I can tell by looking at the [source on GitHub](https://github.com/mapbox/supercluster/blob/a2133d6d354dea559a251c5e3f6a1f16df413ed3/index.js#L172-L181), `getClusterProperties` isn't directly exposed and is used internally by the `superCluster` class. You won't be able to override it.

Comment: @SERG In that case I agree with phuzi and SciFiThief: you can't, and you shouldn't. Generally you never want to override functions provided by libraries, because you risk breaking features.